# C# datetime binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, datetime

I have a textbox I want to bind to DateTime property to an object :

```
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text",myObject,"DateTimeProperty")
myTextBox.DataBindings["Text"].FormatString = "HH:mm";
myTextBox.DataBindings["Text"].FormattingEnabled = true;
myTextBox.DataBindings["Text"].BindingComplete +=
            delegate(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Exception is FormatException)
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong formating, should be :" +myTextBox.DataBindings["Text"].FormatString);
            };
```

This works perfectly, when I change the textbox value, the property change. Now I want the reverse (without parsing the text).

I want to add a button that increment by 1 minutes myObject.DateTimeProperty. The issue is I can't do

```
 myObject.DateTimeProperty.Minutes+=1;
```

nor

```
 myObject.DateTimeProperty = myObject.DateTimeProperty.AddMinutes(1);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you do that? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does myobjoect implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)?

Comment: Seems like he's not using WPF, but Windows Forms databinding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the INotifyPropertyChanged interface works also with Windows Forms. Correct me if I'm wrong.